# How to interrupt synchronous inotify read?

Tags: c++, c, linux, inotify

I want have a background thread constantly reading inotify fd and handling all events. Obviously I also need a way to interrupt this thread, when application closes. I figured the easiest way to achieve this is to close the inotify fd, which will cause the `read` to return `-EBADF`.

Unfortunately, this is not always the case. Sometimes (usually after ~200 iterations) this method hangs - background thread is stuck inside `read`. I noticed that attaching and detaching a debugger is enough to wake the thread and let it finish. Output of `strace -f ./MyApp` illustrates the issue. Normally `read` is resumed after `close`, but sporadically it isn't.

```
[pid 674462] inotify_rm_watch(3, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 674463] read(3, "\1\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0a\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 1024) = 32
[pid 674463] read(3, "\1\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0a\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 1024) = 32
[pid 674463] read(3, "\1\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0a\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 1024) = 32
[pid 674462] <... inotify_rm_watch resumed>) = 0
[pid 674463] read(3, "\1\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0a\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 48
[pid 674462] close(3 <unfinished ...>
[pid 674463] read(3,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 674462] <... close resumed>)       = 0
[pid 674462] futex(0x7f9ae3111910, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 674463, NULL, FUTEX_BITSET_MATCH_ANY
```

Code of minimal reproducer below

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>

void thr(int fd) {
    while (true) {
        const static int bufferSize = 1024;
        char buffer[bufferSize];
        int length = read(fd, buffer, bufferSize);
        if (length < 0) {
            perror("read failed");
            break;
        }

        // ... Handle events, doesn't matter.
    }
    printf("Exiting thread gracefully\n");
}

int main() {
    int fd = inotify_init();
    int wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, ".", IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE | IN_MOVE | IN_MODIFY);

    std::thread t{thr, fd};

    inotify_rm_watch(fd, wd);
    close(fd);

    t.join();
}
```

What is happening inside the hanging `read` call? Is my approach wrong? Should I send some signal to the thread to wake it?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html#NOTES): `"Inotify file descriptors can be monitored using select(2), poll(2), and epoll(7).  When an event is available, the file descriptor indicates as readable"`.  That would allow you to block on a `select` call waiting for either the `inotify` descriptor or one end of a [`pipe`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) to become ready for reading.  Just use the pipe to signal a shutdown request.

Comment: @G.M. perfect, I missed that. Works great, thanks :)